# how to organize the output text in columns from a bat

Tags: microsoft-excel

we put result from a query bat into a txt file, this is result whit the >> C:\Temp\result.txt:

```
{"file":"0345782378ee7a8b48c296a120625fd439ed8699ae857c4f84befeb56e727366","reputation":"BAD","prevalence":"LessThanFifty","firstSeen":"2017-05-08","lastSeen":"2022-05-16","targetOrgs":
{"topCountries":[""]}}{"file":"09a46b3e1be080745a6d8d88d6b5bd351b1c7586ae0dc94d0c238ee36421cafa","reputation":"BAD","prevalence":"Hundreds","firstSeen":"2017-05-12","lastSeen":"2022-07-06","targetOrgs":{"topCountries":
[""]}}{"file":"11d0f63c06263f50b972287b4bbd1abe0089bc993f73d75768b6b41e3d6f6d49","reputation":"BAD","prevalence":"Hundreds","firstSeen":"2017-05-12","lastSeen":"2022-04-08","targetOrgs":{"topCountries":
```

is posible any paremter to organize it something like that?:

```
0345782378ee7a8b48c296a120625fd436 reputation   BAD
0345782378ee7a8b48c296a120625fd439 reputation   GOOD
asdsdsdlkflfkgjfkkb48c296a120625ff reputation   BAD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### A: Reformat your Data for Excel

With some simple character replacement strategies, your data can be transformed to be understood by Excel.

You can use any method you want (automate a script, build into your original batch file, use a text editor of your choice etc.).  I chose to use MS Word since you are using MS Office anyway.

<sup>**NOTE:** Step 1 must precede Step 2.  The order does not matter outside of that</sup>

1. **Replace all** record separators `}{` by a line break `^p`

   [image]
2. **Delete** (replace all with nothing) all remaining instances of `{` and `}`

   [image]  [image]
3. **Replace all** field separators `:` with a comma `,`

   [image]

##### B: Open your Data in Excel

1. Change the **extension** on your `*.txt` file to `*.csv` (comma separated values).
2. Open the `*.csv` file in Excel
   [image]

##### C: Filter Data in Excel

Use `FILTER` function and include only columns you want using `1` or `0` (include or skip).

```
=FILTER(FILTER(A:M,A:A<>""),
   {0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks work very fine,